# When sending an email from sfmc is there a way to update the SF Individual Email Result record? Or has it not been created yet?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

The team would like to supplement the IER records on SF with some data sent to a data extension record. (Create a new field on the IER and populate it with a data extension value).  Now I know how to update a SF record from the email send in SFMC via the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject menthod but I don't know how to get the IER SF id.

Is there another way?
Is the IER in scope at email time?  I am thinking it hasn't been created yet...

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. That would really surprise me. It's like your saying you can update a System Data View that is populated by the system. I couldn't find anything to prove it, maybe someone else can answer this..

Comment: IERs are usually created ~1 hour post send, so the answer is no, you cannot manipulate them at send time. You would have to set up an Automation and schedule it to run at least 1-2 hours after the send.

Comment: Awesome...thank you.  I will have to take another route:)